# Save the terminal output of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just started programming this semester at uni, and I seem to have some issues with this assignment I'm going.

In this section, I need to be able to change directories while saving the history of changed directories. I'm storing the changed values in a list, but when I print the list I'm getting `[NONE]` value.

I'm not sure how else to get the string output of `os.chdir` and store.

```
elif command_arguments[0] == 'changedir':
    if len(command_arguments) >= 2:
        shell_input = shell_input.split(" ")
        os.chdir(shell_input[1])
        changed_dir = os.chdir
        history_list.insert(0, changed_dir)
        print(history_list)
```

Comment: Note that `changed_dir = os.chdir` assigns the *function* `os.chdir` to the name `changed_dir`. This means that `changed_dir` becomes a function that changes your current working directory -- that's not what you wanted!

Answer (score 2):

`os.chdir()` does return `None`, even on success. If you want to save the target-directory in the list you can use `changed_dir = os.getcwd()` right after you changed the directory.

See also: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/os_chdir.htm